# C# BitConverter error

Tags: c#, bitconverter

I am getting an error when i try to start my c# program (please not im not very good a programming so if you could write the answer in very simple terms, that would be appreciated)

```
byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(value));                
PS3.SetMemory(offset, buffer);
```

Here is a picture of there error - http://prntscr.com/7s2uq9

The error reads "The type or namespace name 'GetBytes' does not exist in the namespace 'BitConverter' (are you missing an assembly reference?) "

I have already tried these
- rewriting the code
- rewriting the namespace references at the top (http://prntscr.com/7s2vf6)

My "using Reference things are" -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PS3Lib;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using MetroFramework;
using SimdiBo2;
```

Comment: Can you just include the error message as text instead of a link?

Comment: Ok, give me a minute :)

Comment: And please don't rollback my edit since it removes useless fluff from your question.

Comment: Also put in your `using` statements and namespace please.

Comment: What is your namespace and class of these code put in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a namespace `BitConverter` which confuses the compiler. Either rename your local namespace, or use the fully qualified name for the class:

```
System.BitConverter.GetBytes(...);
```

Comment: @CodeCaster: the error is "The type or namespace GetBytes does not exist in the **namespace BitConverter**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: i cannot find the name space, i remember making one ealier to try resolve the issue, but i deleted it, how can i fix this?

Comment: ill just fully qualify them

Comment: @JacobReid: text search should easily find the namespace. You can use a regex for instance: `namespace.*BitConverter`.